# Retrieving Whois info from a URL/Domain

Tags: python, python-2.7, whois

The `whois` module does not seem to work for me, running this code gives me an error

```
import whois
domains = ['cnn.com']
for dom in domains:
    domain = whois.Domain(dom)
    print domain.registrar
```

This throws this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:\Python27\Practice\2.py", line 5, in 
>   domain = whois.Domain(dom)
>   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\whois_3_adjust.py", line 12, in **init**
>   self.name = data['domain_name'][0].strip().lower()
>   TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str

Tried this query as well:

```
import whois
var = whois.query('google.com')
print var

C:\Python27\python.exe C/Test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Test.py", line 2, in <module>
    var = whois.query('google.com')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\whois\__init__.py", line 50, in query
    pd = do_parse(do_query(d, force, cache_file, slow_down, ignore_returncode), tld)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\whois\_1_query.py", line 44, in do_query
    _do_whois_query(dl, ignore_returncode),
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\whois\_1_query.py", line 58, in _do_whois_query
    p = subprocess.Popen(['whois', '.'.join(dl)], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 711, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 959, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
WindowsError: [Error 2] 

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Can you add the error output you are getting?  Also - what do you mean by "did not work as well"?  What was the issue or difference?  You can respond in a comment, but please update the question with "edit" to clarify whenever possible.

Comment: Also please read the documentation at this site https://github.com/nri-pl/python-whois

Comment: @LightCC wrote the second error. thank you for your comment

Comment: You want `whois.query(url)`, not `whois.whois(url)`

Comment: @ottomeister query also fails edited again

Comment: Ugh. The module is trying to execute an external program called `whois`, but that command does not exist on your system -- or at least, it doesn't exist in a directory that's in your `%PATH%`.  You could try installing the `whois` command from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/whois but I don't know whether this Python module will understand the format of the output of that version of `whois`.